# Uniquely identify an arbitrary object in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, uuid, memoization

I'm trying to create a general [memoizator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) for multiple and arbitrary functions.

For each function `std::function<ReturnType(Args...)>` that we want to memoize, we `unordered_map<Args ..., ReturnType>` (I'm keeping things simple on purpose).

The big problem comes when our memoized function has some really big argument `Args ...`: for example let suppose that our function sort a vector of 10 millions numbers and then returns the sorted vector, so something like `std::function<vector<double>(vector<double>)>`.

As you can imagine, after having inserted less than 100 vectors, we have already filled 8 GBS of memory. Notice that maybe this is given from the combination of huge vectors and the memory required by the sorting algorithm (I didn't investigate on the causes).

So what about if instead of the structure described above, we define `unordered_map<UUID(Args ...), ReturnType>` (where UUID= Universally Unique Identifier)? We should relax the deterministic feature (so maybe we return a wrong error), but with a very low probability.

The problem is that since I never used UUIDs, I don't know if there are suitable implementations for this application.

So my question is:

1. There exists a better solution than UUIDs for this problem?
2. Which UUID implementation is better suitable for this problem?
3. [boost uuid](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html) is a possible candidate?
4. Unfortunately, the problem could be solved for `Args ...` but not for `ReturnType`, so there is a solution for memoized result?

**Notice** that the UUIDs generated for the object `x` should be the same even in different runs and machines.

**Notice** that if we have the same UUID for two different objects (and so we return the wrong value) with a *really* low probability, then it could be acceptable...let's say that this could be a "probabilistic memoizator".

**I know that this application doesn't make sense in a memoization context** (what are the odds that an user asks two times to sort the same 10 millions elements vector?), but it's time and memory expensive (so good for benchmarking and to introduce the memory problem that I stated above), so please don't whip and crucify me because this is an absurd memoization application.

Comment: What do the UUIDs get you? You still have the huge vector breaking your program. And if you don't save the vector you don't benefit from memoization.

Comment: @nwp By "huge vector" you mean the one to be sorted (so the map key) or the sorted one (the map value)? For the first one the problem is solved, since we don't store the vector (but its UUID) as key, for the second one the problem is unsolved (see question 4.).

Comment: ^ What nwp said. And look at hashing to get some kind of quick indication your value /might/ be equivalent to an existing cache entry (you still need to do an exhaustive comparison)

Comment: @sehe if the probability that two UUIDs are equal for different object is very low, then this could acceptable (and part of the framework feature)...Let's say a "probabilistic memoizator".

Comment: I think by UUID you mean hash. There is no generic hashing function that can meaningfully hash everything, you will have to provide overloads for all relevant types. But hashing all the elements in a huge vector isn't exactly fast, so unless you keep sorting the same vector 90% of the time it probably isn't worth it.

Comment: If you task the user with attaching a UUID, then by definition you know that a copy has a different UUID and you might just as well use object identity (`static_cast<void const*>(std::addressof(obj))`). [If you allow copies of UUIDs, then (a) sharing the the object by e.g. `shared_ptr` is superior (b) you are in trouble unless all your values are immutable.]

Comment: Does your memoization mechanism assume that functions have no side affects? because this is not a valid assumption for C++

Comment: @nwp (of course) I know hash, but your I don't understand your osservation: what do you mean by "unless you keep sorting the same vector 90% of the time it probably isn't worth it. "

Comment: @UriBrecher my memoization mechanism assume functions with side effects

Comment: I'm still convinced that UUID is the best choice, quoting from [boost UUID page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html):
"When UUIDs are generated by one of the defined mechanisms, they are either guaranteed to be unique, different from all other generated UUIDs (that is, it has never been generated before and it will never be generated again), or it is extremely likely to be unique (depending on the mechanism)."
Which seems exactly what I need

Comment: Ok, I understood why UUID is not the right choice: their creation is not based on the nature of an object, it's totally independent and so two equals object will have different UUIDs. That's a pity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifying any object is easy. The address is "object identity" in C++. This is also the reason that even empty classes cannot have zero size.

Now, what you want is *value equivalence*. That's strictly not in the language domain. It's solidly in the application/library logic domain.

You should consider using something like `boost::flyweights`. It has precisely this facility, and makes it "easy" to customize the equivalence semantics for your types.

Comment: I've read something on this library, but I don't understand how it could help me. Could you please explain it to me?